# How to check the object of type int[] of an arraylist?

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist, int

I'm trying to find out particular elements in my `ArrayList` (arrayOne). Each element should be an `int[]`. I've tried `System.out.println(arrayOne)`, which compiles but gives a irregular and strange number "[[I@370968]".

I've also tried `System.out.println(arrayOne[0])` but it won't compile and emits the error

> Array required but java.util.ArrayList found.

Given is the following code, with {1,12,3,13,123,2} passed to `eg`:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class arrayTest {
    private ArrayList<int[]> arrayOne; 

    public arrayTest(int[] eg) {
        int[] xy = new int[2];
        arrayOne = new ArrayList<int[]>(eg.length);
        for (int i = 0; i < eg.length; i++) {
            int sv = String.valueOf(eg[i]).length();
            if (sv == 1) {
                xy[0] = 0;
                xy[1] = eg[i];
                arrayOne.add(xy);
            }
            else if (sv == 2) {
                System.out.println("two digits");
                // TODO add code to make xy[0] = the first
                // digit of eg and xy[1] = the second digit
            }
            else {
                System.out.println("too many digits");
                // and throw error accordingly
            }
            System.out.println(arrayOne);
        }
    }
}
```

1. How do make sure and print out the int array at arrayOne[0]
2. Given the code above if (sv == 2)  and i want to split each individual number into an int[] with [0] being the first digit and [1] being the second digit how would i get the int value of each individual digit.

Comment: Please *change* the *title* of your question.It is (kind of) misleading :)

Comment: System.out.println(Arrays.toString(arrayOne)); this will show you properly the array elements.

Comment: @Arin: No it would give compile time errors because of all the overloaded forms of `Arrays.toString()`, none would take an `ArrayList` as parameter.

Comment: yup @ares...just overlooked it.I just want to say what Kayaman has said.+1 for point it.

Answer (score 1):

Use `Arrays.toString(yourArray);` to print out arrays in human readable form.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, the string `[I@370968` is displayed because you are trying to print an `int[]`, which is actually an object. Because this object does not override the object's `toString()` method, that method is derived from the `Object` class. The `Object.toString()` implementation, which prints the class name (in this case `[I`, because it is an int array), then an `@` sign, and then the hash code of the object.

Your `ArrayList` contains a number of `int[]`s. Because an `ArrayList` is not an array (the one with the square brackets, like `int[]`), you can't call an element on it as if it were an array. In short, you cannot call `arrayOne[someDesiredIndex]`.

In order to get an element from the ArrayList, call `get(int index)` on it; it returns the desired `int[]`. As already pointed out by another answer, you can use `Arrays.toString(int[])` to print it in a human readable form.

To answer your questions:

1. You can retrieve the first index (`0`) of the first array inside `arrayOne` with the following code: `arrayOne.get(0)[0]`.
2. The following code should work:

   ```
   private static int[] intToArray(int n) {
       String str = String.valueOf(n);
       int length = str.length();
       int[] ints = new int[length];
       for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
           ints[i] = Integer.parseInt(str.substring(i, i + 1));
       }
       return ints;
   }
   ```

   Above method puts each digit into the next array position (it also works with digits greater than 99). With this method you can easily get each individual digit:

   ```
   int[] digits = intToArray(47);
   int a = digits[0]; // Will be 4
   int b = digits[1]; // Will be 7
   ```

---

So this is the class rewritten:

```
public class Rewrite {

    private ArrayList<int[]> arrayOne = new ArrayList<int[]>();

    public Rewrite(int[] eg) {
        for (int i = 0; i < eg.length; i++) {
            int length = String.valueOf(eg[i]).length();
            switch (length) {
                case 1:
                    this.arrayOne.add(new int[] { 0, eg[i] });
                    break;
                case 2:
                    this.arrayOne.add(intToArray(eg[i]));
                    break;
                default:
                    throw new IllegalArgumentException("Number " + eg[i] + " has too many digits");
                    // Or display the error or something.
            }
            System.out.println(Arrays.toString(this.arrayOne.get(i)));
        }
    }

    private static int[] intToArray(int n) {
        String str = String.valueOf(n);
        int length = str.length();
        int[] ints = new int[length];
        for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
            ints[i] = Integer.parseInt(str.substring(i, i + 1));
        }
        return ints;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Rewrite r = new Rewrite(new int[] { 47, 53, 91, 8 });
    }
```